# How to create a global variables whose values are calculated based on objects on a class?

Tags: python, class, global-variables

I'm just starting with Python via the good old banking assignment. One question is to set two global variables in the class: total_balance and total_customer, with the former being the sum of balances of all customers (floating point values) and the latter the total number of customers (integer). I can't think of a way to declare this within the class.

The class definition is currently:

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, name, balance=0.00):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.balance = float(balance)
```

Answer (score 2):

By global variables you should be referring to class variables, whose values are class-wide and not bound to an instance. In your case, the `total_balance` and `total_customer` class variables can be defined like this, so that the instantiation of each new `BankAccount` object will increment the two class variables accordingly:

```
class BankAccount:
    total_balance = 0.0
    total_customer = 0

    def __init__(self, name, balance=0.0):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.total_balance += balance
        self.total_customer += 1
```

Comment: Ooohh. The instruction says "global" so I tried to stick to that and have not considered a nested solution like this. That being said, I thought each instantiation of each new object is run independent from the previous? I've tried with 2 objects and there is no incrementing.

Comment: Only instance variables of an instance are independent from those of another instance. Class variables, on the other hand, are shared across all instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would be sufficient?

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, name, balance=0.00):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.balance = float(balance)

def total_all_accounts(account_list):
    total = 0
    for account in account_list:
        total += account.balance
    print("Total held in bank: ${0:.2f}".format(total))
    print("Total number of customers: {}".format(len(account_list)))

myList = []
for i in range(25):
    account = BankAccount('John Doe', balance=5.00)
    myList.append(account)

total_all_accounts(myList)
```

This creates a list of object (all customers are "John Doe" and deposited $5.00 when making their account). We then have a function that goes and grabs the information from this list and totals it in terms of customers as well as total deposited. You would probably want to change how the list is made so customers have different names and account balances, but I think this example shows how to store objects in lists and access their attributes within functions!

For me this outputs:

> Total held in bank: $125.00
>
> Total number of customers: 25

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer with the question. I did think of using loop, but I'm stuck at the exact way to create the list from, say, objects created from this class. E.g. yuri = BankAccount(name = "Yuri", balance = 100) and anna = BankAccount(name = "Anna", balance = 1000)

Comment: @ThaiNguyen You can just say `myList.append(BankAccount('Yuri', balance=100.00))`